# Swift 2.0: use of self in method call before stored properties are initialised

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

Just started looking at Swift this weekend.  I'm creating an id for my class to quickly compare objects.  I want an immutable id, so should use let.

Using var and initialising id to "" will fix *"use of self in method call before stored properties are initialised"* but then of course it's mutable.  Every other question i've seen similar to this is regarding a super class / calling super.init, which I don't have.  It's very frustrating, I don't know why it's not straightforward.

```
class MagicCard {

    let id:String
    let name: String
    let manaCost: Int
    let description: String
    let attack: Int
    let defence: Int

    init (name: String, manaCost: Int, description: String, attack: Int, defence: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.manaCost = manaCost
        self.description = description
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        id = generateRandomID()
    }

    private func generateRandomID() -> String {
        let charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let charSetArray = Array(charSet.characters)
        var id:String = ""
        for _ in (0..<10) {
            id.append(charSetArray[Int(arc4random()) % charSetArray.count])
        }
        return id
    }
}

func == (lhs: MagicCard, rhs: MagicCard) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the property to the function? It's a class method, so has access to id. Inside the initialiser, you could call `generateRandomID()` and it will have access to `id`

Comment: @Mark: That would not work because you can not modify `id` from the method if it is declared as a *constant* with `let`.

Comment: Consider using existing `NSUUID` to properly generate an unique identifier; you can simplify the code by removing the entire `generateRandomID()` (which might not always even be unique). You also have the problem of using `arc4random() % n` instead of `arc4random_uniform(n)` – there is a difference in the resulting randomness when `n` does not divide the range of random numbers generated, which it doesn't in this case (the difference may be negligible with such a small `n`, but never-the-less).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `generateRandomID()` method does not use or modify any properties
of the instance, so one possible solution would be to make it a
*type (class)* method:

```
private class func generateRandomID() -> String {
    // ...
    return id
}
```

and use it like

```
id = MagicCard.generateRandomID()
```

(as also written in the other answer while I was writing this).

You could also drop the method and use an "immediately evaluated closure":

```
id = { () -> String in
    // ...
    return id
}()
```

**But** if the intention of the id property is to make the objects
`Equatable` then **you don't need it** at all. Classes are reference
types and instances can be compared with the "identical to" operator:

```
func == (lhs: MagicCard, rhs: MagicCard) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

which makes the `id` and the `generateRandomID()` method obsolete.

Comment: Cheers for that Martin.  I've found the whole thing very strange, I've never encountered something like that in any other OO language i've used.  I wanted to make the class Equatable so that I could extend the array class to have a "removeObject:<T>object" function.

Comment: @SparkyRobinson I *think* this is happening because checking wether all your variables are initialized once and only once is an undecidable problem if you allow your `init` methods to call other, potentially mutating methods. Other OO languages that enforce the same constraints would have the same issues.

Answer (score 9):

A hot-fix I can suggest is to make `generateRandomID` a class func. So make it like so :

```
private class func generateRandomID() -> String {
```

And call like this :

```
id = MagicCard.generateRandomID()
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling the member function `generateRandomID` includes an implicit `self.`, so you cannot indeed do it before the object is fully initialised. A simple solution would be first assigning a temporary value to `id`:

```
id = ""
id = generateRandomID() // NOT THE SUGGESTED SOLUTION, see below.
```

But to do that you'd have to change it to a `var`, and then it'd take more effort to hide the setter from the public.

However, nothing in `generateRandomID()` depends on the state of the object, so it might as well be a `static` class function, which you would then call as `MagicCard.generateRandomID()`. But to take it even further, conceptually the generation of a random id doesn't have anything to with a Magic card, so you could even make it a global function or isolate it to a class of its own…

…and once we get that far, why not just use the existing `NSUUID` type to represent your id? Either change the type of `id` to `NSUUID` and initialise it with `id = NSUUID()` for a random UUID, or keep it a `String` and assign as `id = NSUUID().UUIDString`. UUIDs already solve the problem of unique ids, so you don't have to come up with your own generator. =)

This leads us to:

```
let id: NSUUID = NSUUID()
```

or

```
let id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
```